# Is there a way to define a generic parameter type explicitly in a lambda expression?

Tags: java, generics, lambda

I have here a `Handler` class, which is supposed to handle `Event`s of a certain type:

```
public interface Handler<E extends Event>
{
    public void handle(E event);

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public default Class<E> getEventType()
    {
        for(Method method: this.getClass().getDeclaredMethods())
        {
            if(method.getName().equals("handle")) return (Class<E>)method.getParameterTypes()[0];
        }
        throw new NullPointerException("Couldn't find the 'handle' method in this handler.");
    }
}
```

As you can see, it will try, by default, to get the type of `Event` by returning the first parameter type of the `handle()` method whenever you execute `getEventType()` (as opposed to a `Handler` that returns it explicitly). This works correctly with the following JUnit test:

```
public static class EmptyEvent extends Event
{
    public void test() { }
}

public static Handler<EmptyEvent> genericHandler = new Handler<EmptyEvent>()
{
    @Override
    public void handle(EmptyEvent event)
    {

    }
};

@Test
public void testEventGenerics()
{
    //prints the name of EmptyEvent
    System.out.println(genericHandler.getEventType());
}
```

Intellij IDEA tells me that I can simplify `genericHandler` to a lambda expression, so I do that:

```
public static class EmptyEvent extends Event
{
    public void test() { }
}

public static Handler<EmptyEvent> genericHandler = event -> { };

@Test
public void testEventGenerics()
{
    //prints the name of the base Event class
    System.out.println(genericHandler.getEventType());
}
```

however, the test prints out the name of `Event`, not `EmptyEvent`.

So my question is, **Is there a way to explicitly define the generic parameter type of a lambda expression?**

I tried doing something like this, but it doesn't do anything (also it's an error)

```
public static Handler<EmptyEvent> genericHandler = (EmptyEvent)event -> { };
```

Answer (score 5):

Yes you can define the type of a lambda expression parameter:

```
public static Handler<EmptyEvent> genericHandler = (EmptyEvent event) -> { };
```

In general it is not necessary because it is implied by context. However it often makes the code easier to read.

See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.27 for more details

Comment: Hmm. It compiles and this answers the question, but for some reason `genericHandler.getEventType()` still returns the name of `Event`. Would you have any idea why?

Comment: @Octopod possibly because you're relying on the order that different methods get returned by `getDeclaredMethods`, which is a no-no.

Comment: @immibis except that I'm pretty sure that there is only one `handle()` method (the one I defined), isn't there? Are you saying there's also a `handle(Event)` too?

Comment: @Octopod Yes; it's a bridge method. I don't know whether it will be returned from getDeclaredMethods, but apparently it is.

Comment: @immibis, I changed `getEventType()` to print out every method named `handle`. `handle(Event)` is the only method it found using `getDeclaredMethods()`. `getMethods()` returns the same thing.

Comment: @Octopod ...okay, that is not what I expected.

Answer (score 1):

You are making assumptions about the class of the object that the lambda evaluates to, and I don't think those assumptions are valid. It is sufficient that the lambda overrides the method `handle()` from `Handler`, and at runtime, a `handle()` method that takes `Event` is sufficient to override the `handle()` from `Handler`, which after erasure takes `Event`. Nowhere is it guaranteed that the lambda must have a `handle()` method that can be introspected to say that it takes `EmptyEvent`.

Answer (score 0):

The following variables might all point to the same object!

```
Handler<EventA> handlerA = event -> { };
Handler<EventB> handlerB = event -> { };

Consumer<String> consumer1 = string -> {}
Consumer<Integer> consumer2 = integer-> {}
```

You cannot really reason about the exact runtime type of a lambda expression; the only guarantee is that the lambda body works at runtime.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.27.4

> The [runtime] method's body has the **effect** of evaluating the lambda body